# bootstrap carousel bottom space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

hi i have carousel but carousel have bottom white space [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fubz.jpg)
i how fix this ?  my code here.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active"><img src="public/slider/1.jpg"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/2.jpg"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/3.jpg"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/4.jpg"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/5.jpg"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's due to the image size. You will need to edit your images to all be the same height and width. Otherwise you will have that blank space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active"><img src="public/slider/1.jpg" height="200" width="400"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/2.jpg" height="200" width="400"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/3.jpg" height="200" width="400"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/4.jpg" height="200" width="400"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="public/slider/5.jpg" height="200" width="400"><div class="carousel-caption">bas</div></div>
        </div>
```

Or you can edit the width and height of the images manually before the upload. I suggest doing it manually because setting the width and height via HTML can distort the image sometimes.